# reference for regime shifting models

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling, time-series

I'm looking for a good introduction to regime shifting models. It would be nice to see things like simple example of regime shifting models, ways to detect a regime shift in data, fitting regime shifting models, and so on. Any suggestions?

Comment: Some context might help. Presumably this refers to structural breaks in time series - add relevant tags.